# How to drop the end of an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator

[Array#drop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-drop) removes the first *n* elements of an array. What is a good way to remove the last *m* elements of an array? Alternately, what is a good way to keep the middle elements of an array (greater than *n*, less than *m*)?

Comment: Because you can index into an array in ruby with a range, it might be convenient to just assign the middle elements to a new array and use that.  foo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
bar = foo[2..4]
=> [3, 4, 5]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use Array#slice method, e.g.:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].slice(1..4) # => [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

or

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a.take 3 # => [1, 2, 3]
a.first 3 # => [1, 2, 3]
a.first a.size - 1 # to get rid of the last one
```

Comment: there is also `Array#slice!`, when in-place array modification is needed.

Comment: `Array#slice!` does not seem to do anything different from `Array#slice`.

Answer (score 29):

This is exactly what [`Array#pop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pop) is for:

```
x = [1,2,3]
x.pop(2) # => [2,3]
x # => [1]
```

Comment: @ggPeti: I'm aware of that. The title of the question seem to imply that the OP indeed wants to change the original array.

Comment: This is the correct answer considering OP's request to **remove** the last m elements. Pop removes them from the original array whereas drop or slice creates a new array.

Answer (score 4):

The most direct opposite of `drop` (drop the first n elements) would be `take`, which keeps the first n elements (there's also `take_while` which is analogous to `drop_while`).

Slice allows you to return a subset of the array either by specifying a range or an offset and a length. Array#[] behaves the same when passed a range as an argument or when passed 2 numbers

Answer (score 1):

this will get rid of last n elements:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
n = 4
p a[0, (a.size-n)]

#=> [1, 2]

n = 2
p a[0, (a.size-n)]
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

regard "middle" elements:

```
min, max = 2, 5
p a.select {|v| (min..max).include? v }
#=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the return value to be the array without the dropped elements. I found a couple solutions here to be okay:

```
count = 2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].slice 0..-(count + 1) # => [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].tap { |a| a.pop count } # => [1, 2, 3]
```

But I found another solution to be more readable if the order of the array isn't important (in my case I was deleting files):

```
count = 2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reverse.drop count # => [3, 2, 1]
```

You could tack another `.reverse` on there if you need to preserve order but I think I prefer the `tap` solution at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same as `Array#pop` in a non destructive way, and without needing to know the lenght of the array:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = a[0..-2]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = 3 # if we want drop the last n elements
c = a[0..-(n+1)]
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Array#delete_at() is the simplest way to delete the last element of an array, as so

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr.delete_at(-1)
p arr # => [1,2,3,4,5]
```

For deleting a segment, or segments, of an array use methods in the other answers.

Comment: Vijay, your comment that "you have to call arr again to get [1,2,3,4,5]" makes no sense. You do need to call arr again to see the effect of delete_at method. But that is true for any method you run on an array... or any other datatype. My answer remains a valid solution to the problem posed by OP.

Comment: Sorry, late night. Missed the puts for the arr value. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score -2):

You can also add some methods

```
class Array

  # Using slice
  def cut(n)
    slice(0..-n-1)
  end

  # Using pop
  def cut2(n)
    dup.tap{|x| x.pop(n)}
  end

  # Using take
  def cut3(n)
    length - n >=0 ? take(length - n) : []
  end

end

[1,2,3,4,5].cut(2)
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: as I see here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pop is a bang! method and returns poped elements instead of resulting array, and you should use dup for it or to use in tne tap of the object like ary.tap{|x| x.drop(2)}

Comment: Actually, your method correspond to `last(n)`. Note also that the `length` is not needed in your method

Comment: #last Returns the last element(s) of self. If the array is empty, the first form returns nil. My methods returns self with cuted tail by n

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune also it's the same to my_array.dup.tap{|x| x.pop(n)}

Comment: It's generally bad practice to monkey patch native code.